# Django "render" is not accessed Pylance

Tags: python, django, visual-studio

After creating an app, in the file "views.py" the import "from django.shortcuts import render" says django "render" is not accessed Pylance
[image: code with the message]

hello>views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("hello")
```

lecture3>settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'hello',
]
```

hello>urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    path("",views.index, name="index")
]
```

lecture3>urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.urls.conf import include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('helllo/', include("hello.urls"))
]
```

[image: webpage message error]

Comment: It simply says that you import something that is not used later in the program.

Answer (score 1):

It simply says that you import something that is not used later in the program. You thus have imported `render`, but no view is making a call to `render`, or passing a reference to the `render` function for example.

The same with the request parameter, it is not used when you construct a `HttpResponse('Hello')`. Usually if you import something, or you define a parameter for something, you use that something in the rest of the code. The message thus warns you that you might have forgotten something. You can here thus remove the `from django.shortcuts import render` line.

Comment: i have edited my post showing all what i did, based in CS50W course going line by line, it is supposed to work, thx

Comment: @JulianGomez: normally it *will* work, these are just *warnings*, not *errors*.

Answer (score 0):

If you have not figured it out, it is not loading because you did not change the URL to /hello/.

During that lecture, as he was saying to run the program, he tells you to change the URL to IP:PORT/hello/.

I had the same problem.